# Why we never tried our hand in Community promotion ads?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Community Promotion ad give us chance to advertise on graduate sites, so we can attract users from there. It can also be done with Area 51 page but that looks too weak for a public beta site. Why didn't we try to make one for us?

For example, refer any graduate site's meta post tagged with [community-ads](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads).

We can try with [christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4313/community-promotion-ads-2015). Or on any related graduate site with a good image.

Read [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1745/community-promotion-ads-2015?cb=1) for more detail about Community Promotion ad.

Few attempts made by other SE beta sites ( [Health](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/community-promotion-ads), [mythology](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/community-promotion-ads)).

Feel free to give your suggestions and advice in answers.

Comment: It has been my experience (in USA) that Christians are the least willing to understand Hinduism. My grandma's pastor was from India and he told me as a child that Hindus worshiped chickens. That didn't sound right  So, if you are going to advertise on that site, maybe ask questions like "What does God say about ____?" Also, I remember seeing a question on here about "Can a Christian really be a Hindu, too?" Something like that might pique interest. Lastly, my experience with Biblical Hermeneutics SE has been that there are more believers than scholars there. So, maybe use a similar approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> #### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:
>
> - interesting unix and linux related open source apps
> - the site's twitter account
> - script packs or power tools
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

So, There are three important factors affect regarding to advertising our site:

- To find the proper and suitable ground i.e related site(s) which we can try our hands on.
- Determining what type of poster may work. What ideas or questions we can frame as an advertising poster.
- Response of our ads. It is not easy to predict how will community react.

I've tried (without fearing much!) to promote our community by means of Community Promotion Ads 2017 on following sites:

1. [Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6245/33362):

   [image]
2. [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9595/83616):

   [image]
3. [Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3351/17262):

   [image]
4. [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2631/1190): <sup>/cc @[Ankit Sharma](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35251460#35251460)</sup>

   [image]
5. [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3585/41289):

   [image]

---

- If you want to share our area51 proposal then just copy the following code and paste it in answer body:

  `[![image](https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/53689.png)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism)` (links to Area51 page)

  OR `[![image](https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/53689.png)](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/join)` (links to join this community)

  [image]

---

**Note**: If the ads are not relevant or suitable with the community, then it may looks like spam!

Comment: Christianity have better coloring ( suiting favicon more) and Hinduism.SE in Christianity  ad looks more clean then Hinduism stackexchnage in physics ad which is touching both the corners and not looking clean.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thanks for pointing out. Just updated.

Comment: can't upvote more ;)

Comment: wow...this must be the official way of spamming each other :)

Comment: I don't think the physics one is good. There are 3 downvotes already. That site is filled with skeptics. Try another one relating to atom/molecule concept.

Comment: @sv. Revised the post to explain properly.

Comment: @SreeCharan other site don't always receive things positively but there is no harm in trying. If you have a better or different idea, feel free to express it in answers here.

Comment: Only philosophy is doing fine and looks best too, maybe it's better if people from here can appreciate in those places

Comment: @SreeCharan Physics ad is updated.

Comment: nice........ :)

Comment: Movies & TV ad got 6 votes too

Comment: "But there is no harm in trying" Actually, there might be. Bad advertising can be worse than no advertising. Successful marketing requires precise use of specific media theory techniques

Comment: If you ask, "Want to learn *Hindu* Philosophy?" it doesn't connect to something they already know. So, they have little reason to click. You can connect them with something like, "How is *Advaita Vedanta* like Neoplatonism?" or even, "Neoplatonism in ancient India!?" For the physics one a slight alteration to "What do ancient Indian texts say about gravity?" Chemistry and Movies/TV are pretty good. I will think on the Christianity one.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can choose questions/answers with highest votes or highest number of views and then to choose among them to used for Advertising. Advertising should not be limited to just Stack Exchange sites, we should expand advertising/commenting/linking on other Hinduism sites/blogs. I can remember that I have seen many misleading articles on a site (www.SpeakingTree.in). It would be best to comment over there linking to the correct answers which are present on Hinduism SE.

Regarding the Christian SE and other religion SE, I don't think that it would be the right place as every religious person considers his religion on priority and would not like to visit into much details of other religion. On the other hand, the person viewing any blog or site consisting of Hinduism, is already interested in the subject and can get more enlightened by coming here and getting correct facts as per scriptures.

Also, not to forget, please do mention in the ads about the fact that the answers here are as per what is mentioned in the scriptures which is along with the proof texts, so that should get more attention.

Comment: Our site has FB and twitter accounts created by our former moderators(probably). Activity of the accounts are very poor. We can post top questions of the week and month in Social media to get more attention.

Answer (score 2):

Places to advertise:

- Sanskrit Language
- Philosophy
- History
- Academia
- Buddhism
- Biblical Hermeneutics
- Vegetarianism
- Speculative Science

---

Hopefully someone can make this look better, but here is one of my ideas for the Christian & Biblical Hermeneutics SEs.

[image]

Comment: Nice thought, but too much text, IMO.

Comment: I agree, it is too busy. This is why I don't do graphics 

Comment: Only graduated sites have community ads. Only philosophy is a graduated  site among the ones you have mentioned.

Comment: Ohhh! I never realized so many are in Beta still. Wow!

Comment: Not beta, some didn't even make to private beta.

Comment: I can't understand why SE is so strict with its requirements. I believe knowledge should be freely and widely shared when requested, even if there are few people who have that specific knowledge or few people asking about that specific knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is not the answer we are expecting , but maybe we could also promote a number of others sites as well, such as the following:

[image]

In fostering other sites we may be spreading adherents to [Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions).

Here is how Christianity Meta has to say for [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6225/community-promotion-ads-2017). This response is more simply an example of my thoughts on this subject.

Answer (score -3):

I have a thought but as I am not a designer, I will just write down the text and expect any designer will change it to a beautiful design. (*Also rephrase for better promotion*)

> #### Internet points are Imaginary and virtual,
>
> #### Wanna try some real KARMA points?
>
> #### Visit Hinduism.SE now!!